# Relationship between the t-statistic of a coefficient in an OLS multivariate regression and Ridge shrinkage?

Tags: regression, regularization, ridge-regression

If I'm running a multivariate OLS regression and look at the t-stats of coefficients, is it the case that the coefficients with smaller t-stats are shrunk relatively more if I were to run the same terms with a Ridge regression? Is there a relationship between the t-stat from OLS and the magnitude of shrinkage from the same terms run with a ridge regression penalty?